# ImportError: cannot import name 'url' from 'django.conf.urls django #Python #Django #VisualStudioCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, python-3.10, django-4.0

I have been trying to write a simple django website. Unfortunately I am having errors with trying to import bayaan.urls (the app) into the urls.py(of the project).

This is the error:

```
(test) C:\Users\---\Documents\------\Django\apps\School>python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\---\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 1009, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\---\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 946, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\---\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\---\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 124, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\---\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 438, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "C:\Users\---\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 77, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "C:\Users\---\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\---\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\---\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 446, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\---\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\---\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 632, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\---\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\---\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 625, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\---\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\---\Documents\----\Django\apps\School\School\urls.py", line 20, in <module>
    path('bayaan/', include('bayaan.urls')),
  File "C:\Users\---\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\---\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\---\Documents\---\Django\apps\School\bayaan\urls.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.conf.urls import url
ImportError: cannot import name 'url' from 'django.conf.urls' (C:\Users\---\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\conf\urls\__init__.py)
```

This is my code (in bayaan(the app)):

```
from django.conf.urls import url 
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.home, name='home')]
```

This is the code in the School folder(The project):

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('bayaan/', include('bayaan\urls.py')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

I've tried using re_path with no luck.
By the way, I'm using python 3.10.1 as well as django 4.0.1. My code editor is Visual Studio Code.

ps. I'm using windows.

Answer (score 0):

The url() method was removed in Django 4.0. Look at the release notes here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/releases/4.0/#features-removed-in-4-0

- django.conf.urls.url() is removed

But in your case, you're not using the *url* method only *path* (supported in Django 4.0), so only remove the import line from your code

```
from django.conf.urls import url
```

For more details how Django processes a request (using *path* and *re-path* methods) see the documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request